# Scroll error al bajar para cambiar de color

Tags: javascript

Al bajar el scroll y cambiar de color mi menú, me sale que no esta definido [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: error de scroll]imgur.com/cDnGn.png
[image: consola]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad, edita tu pregunta y coloca el código en Texto, ya que de esa manera se hace mas fácil poder reproducir el error y por lo consiguiente se te podrá ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

y si pruebas de insertar html o body?

```
$("html").scroll(function(){
   // tu codigo
});
```

Ademas en tu código hay esto:

```
export const menu = () =>{
  $("html").scroll(function(){
     // tu codigo
  });
}
```

Y puede ser que el export este dando este error. No estoy seguro

Comment: si acaba de funcionar, muchas garcías